# byobu: 2 status bars when ssh into another byobu . How to remove the first?

Tags: debian, byobu

When I ssh into my server I get the byobu status bar added to the bottom. But it keeps the one of the local computer session. I imagine it will add a 3rd if I ssh into another one.

How can I keep only the last one ?